# what is the syntax to call asynchronously Ajax.ActionLink in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web form and i want to call Asynchronously Ajax.ActionLink().
Please help me to find out the syntax to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you can call asynchronously Gettime Function in Controller .

```
         <%= Ajax.ActionLink("UTC", "GetTime", new { zone = "utc" },
         new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" }) %>
         <%= Ajax.ActionLink("BST", "GetTime", new { zone = "bst" },
         new AjaxOptions { Confirm="bst" }) %>
         <%= Ajax.ActionLink("MDT", "GetTime", new { zone = "mdt" },
         new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" }) %>
```